# Dynamic Contract generation using existing PDF

Tags: apex, email, email-template, pdf

I have a contract template PDF file. I want to send this contract to multiple contacts or users, but with their respective names on PDF. For example, If PDF is like below

Hi Mark,

This is content.

Thank You

Then If I am sending to Daniel, Mark should be replaced with Daniel.
I researched if we can edit PDF in salesforce and I think we cannot. But is there any alternate solution to achieve this.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You want to send this as a pdf  attachment by email?

Comment: Yes. I have PDF template, which should automatically be filled as per contact. Then that PDF I have to send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a document merge app like Conga Composer or Nintex Drawloop.  See the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=document%20merge).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Classic Email Template to create email content. Add text where dynamic content like

```
Hi {!Case.Name},
```

Replace this {!Case.Name} from Apex call with actual values. Use EmailTemplate with Messaging.SingleEmailMessage to generate PDF.